# Changing Webcam identifiers

Tags: linux, webcam

Recently I tried testing whether my webcam is accessible to the browser(used google chrome) properly or not. I  gave the camera access to a website (https://webcamtests.com/)  for the test and it was able to read the webcam name after giving access. I don't want to reveal such information to any website.

Is there any way to change the identifiers of a webcam like webcam name, Vendor name on Linux? I made a .hwdb  file on /etc/udev/hwdb.d/ with bus, vendor, and product id by following some random tutorial

```
evdev:input:b0003v80eep0030*
 ID_VENDOR=Someone
```

and updated using `systemd-hwdb update` but it doesn't change anything

I don't know whether I did it correctly and if there is a way to modify those identifiers